# Django dictionary object shows nothing in template but prints to console

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Following Django's tutorials https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly I have called a stored a procedure and populated a dictionary object.

**Views.py**

```
@login_required
def team_edit(request):
    user_instance = request.user
    user_id = user_instance.id

    cursor = connection.cursor()   
    cursor.execute("CALL test(%s)", user_id) #Call db stored procedure

    results = dictfetchall(cursor)

    print(results)

    return render_to_response('team_edit.html',results, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

# Converts a list to a dict 
def dictfetchall(cursor):
    "Returns all rows from a cursor as a dict"
    desc = cursor.description
    return [
        dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]
```

Printing `print(results)` shows in the console:

`[{'private_league_name': "Root's League", 'host_user_id': 1}, {'private_league_name': "Joe's League", 'host_user_id': 3}]`

However the list in the template shows **nothing**:

```
   <h2>Results Test</h2><br>

        <ul>
            {% for key, value in results.items %}
            <li> {{ key }}: {{ value }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
```

Why is this?

Comment: based on [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) you must pass `dictionary` as second argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what the dictionary is used for when calling `render_to_response`. If I were to call

```
return render_to_response('team_edit.html',{'customer_id' : 5}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I would effectively be able to use

```
{{customer_id}}
```

Somewhere in my template.

In this case, you want

```
return render_to_response('team_edit.html',{'results' : results}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

However, notice that your `results` variable is a *list*, not a *dictionary*, so in your template you will need something like

```
{% for result in results %}
    {% for key, value in result %}
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Why is `results` still a list though? I thought it was converted? :/

Comment: @Matchday the general idea is that in the `render_to_response` dictionary, you have `{'context_variable_name' : actual_variable_in_controller}`. In this case, the `results` variable in your controller is indeed a list of dictionaries. There is no implicit conversion.

Comment: I understand but in the Django docs I thought `dictfetchall(cursor)` was supposed to convert the list into a dict object

Comment: @Matchday the intention of `dictfetchall` to create dictionary *per row*, not out of all the rows in the result. So intuitively you have a list of dictionaries, each dictionary corresponds to a row. You can't have one dictionary because you can only have one unique key per dictionary. Notice that `fetchall()` normally returns tuples.

Answer (score 2):

change `return` line in `view.py` like this:

```
return render_to_response('team_edit.html',{'results':results}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```